# Logging in Microsoft Azure TableController

Tags: c#, azure, logging, mobile, service

Can someone tell me how to log from a TableController class (Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server)? I have seen a few places (such as https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/04/24/logging-with-the-net-backend-for-azure-mobile-services/) that say to user the TableController Services member, Log property and to call the logging methods from there--this.Services.Log.Info("log text"). But I don't see any Services member of the TableController class.

Thanks, 
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Services property only works under Azure Mobile Services. In Azure Mobile App, The Services property is no longer part of the SDK. Logging is now accomplished using the standard ASP.NET trace writing.

```
ITraceWriter traceWriter = this.Configuration.Services.GetTraceWriter();
traceWriter.Info("Hello, World");
```

For more information, link below is for your reference.

[Upgrade your existing .NET Azure Mobile Service to App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services)